# Symlink for README.md file

Tags: git, symlink, msys2

I'm trying to create a few symlinks inside my GitHub Repo. the File Structure is as below:

```
learn.coding
|- .readmes
|-|- <AboluteBeginner>
|-|-|- <README1.md>
|-|- <InpputandOutput>
|-|-|- <README2.md>

|- learn.bash
|-|- <folder1>
|-|-|- <README1.md> <-- I want this to be the symlink
|-|- <folder1>
|-|-|- <README2.md> <-- I want this to be the symlink
```

How to Implement this?

I tried the following command to create a symlink at my desired location mentioned above using Git Bash. But, No Luck.

```
abhinavbharadwajr@Bora-Beast MINGW64 ~/OneDrive/Documents/abr.repo
$ cd learn.coding/

abhinavbharadwajr@Bora-Beast MINGW64 ~/OneDrive/Documents/abr.repo/learn.coding (master)
$ ls -l
total 52
drwxr-xr-x 1 abhinavbharadwajr 197608     0 Nov 26 18:28 learn.bash/
drwxr-xr-x 1 abhinavbharadwajr 197608     0 Nov 26 13:40 learn.cpp/
drwxr-xr-x 1 abhinavbharadwajr 197608     0 Nov 26 18:42 learn.java/
drwxr-xr-x 1 abhinavbharadwajr 197608     0 Nov 26 18:41 learn.python/
-rw-r--r-- 1 abhinavbharadwajr 197608 35802 Jun 13  2021 LICENSE
-rw-r--r-- 1 abhinavbharadwajr 197608  1031 Nov 26 16:14 README.md

abhinavbharadwajr@Bora-Beast MINGW64 ~/OneDrive/Documents/abr.repo/learn.coding (master)
$ cd learn.bash/

abhinavbharadwajr@Bora-Beast MINGW64 ~/OneDrive/Documents/abr.repo/learn.coding/learn.bash (master)
$ ls -l
total 0
drwxr-xr-x 1 abhinavbharadwajr 197608 0 Nov 26 20:30 AbsoluteBeginner/
drwxr-xr-x 1 abhinavbharadwajr 197608 0 Nov 26 18:28 InputandOutput/

abhinavbharadwajr@Bora-Beast MINGW64 ~/OneDrive/Documents/abr.repo/learn.coding/learn.bash (master)
$ cd AbsoluteBeginner/

abhinavbharadwajr@Bora-Beast MINGW64 ~/OneDrive/Documents/abr.repo/learn.coding/learn.bash/AbsoluteBeginner (master)
$ ls -l
total 0

abhinavbharadwajr@Bora-Beast MINGW64 ~/OneDrive/Documents/abr.repo/learn.coding/learn.bash/AbsoluteBeginner (master)
$ ln -s learn.coding/.readmes/Absolute Beginner/README.md README.md
ln: target 'README.md': No such file or directory

abhinavbharadwajr@Bora-Beast MINGW64 ~/OneDrive/Documents/abr.repo/learn.coding/learn.bash/AbsoluteBeginner (master)
$ touch README.md

abhinavbharadwajr@Bora-Beast MINGW64 ~/OneDrive/Documents/abr.repo/learn.coding/learn.bash/AbsoluteBeginner (master)
$ ln -s learn.coding/.readmes/Absolute Beginner/README.md README.md
ln: target 'README.md': Not a directory

abhinavbharadwajr@Bora-Beast MINGW64 ~/OneDrive/Documents/abr.repo/learn.coding/learn.bash/AbsoluteBeginner (master)
$ ln -s ../../../README.md README.md
ln: failed to create symbolic link 'README.md': File exists

abhinavbharadwajr@Bora-Beast MINGW64 ~/OneDrive/Documents/abr.repo/learn.coding/learn.bash/AbsoluteBeginner (master)
$ rm -r README.md 

abhinavbharadwajr@Bora-Beast MINGW64 ~/OneDrive/Documents/abr.repo/learn.coding/learn.bash/AbsoluteBeginner (master)
$ ln -s ../../../README.md README.md
ln: failed to create symbolic link 'README.md': No such file or directory
```

I don't know what I'm doing wrong. Can anyone Help me?

Comment: If your directory names contain whitespace, you have to quote or escape them. Also, you're on Windows, I'm not sure if you can create symbolic links there.

Comment: Also, get your relative paths right.  If your command starts with `ln -s learn.coding/` there needs to be a `learn.coding` directory inside the current directory.  You can use `../` to go up a level.

Comment: `%20` does not mean anything in Bash.  Use `\ ` or quotes around the path.

Comment: @DavidGrayson I tries this command `ln -s .readmes/AbsoluteBeginner/README.md learn.bash/AbsoluteBeginner/README.md` but yet I receive the message `ln: failed to create symbolic link 'learn.bash/AbsoluteBeginner/README.md': No such file or directory` why is this Happening.

I gave this command from being in the Root of the Repo Dircetory like this: `abhinavbharadwajr@Bora-Beast MINGW64 ~/OneDrive/Documents/abr.repo/learn.coding (master)
$ ln -s .readmes/AbsoluteBeginner/README.md learn.bash/AbsoluteBeginner/README.md`

Comment: According to the file structure you posted there are no subdirectories inside `.readmes` so your command is just wrong.  If you updated you file structure, please edit your question to include the output of the `find` command (excluding .git).

Comment: @DavidGrayson File Structure has been updated in the Question.

Answer (score 0):

Try running `export MSYS=winsymlinks` before the `ln -s ...` command.

For more information about the `MSYS` environemnt variable, which was called `CYGWIN` in CygWin, see:

https://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/using-cygwinenv.html